# How to check the url with javascript / jquery even if their is a trailing slash?

Tags: jquery, url, window, location, addclass

I have two panels with a list of links inside of them being used as a sidebar on a blog. One of the panels will expand if it contains a link to the current url.

The problem is if a trailing slash is added at the end of the current url it no longer works. How could I achieve this so it works regardless of whether or not the url has a trailing slash?

Here's the current code I'm using:

```
jQuery('.list-group-item a[href$="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass("active").parents('.panel .panel-heading a').collapse('show');
```

And here's a live example:

http://s.codepen.io/bootstrapped/debug/jqWXmM

But if you visit this it doesn't work (note the trailing slash):

http://s.codepen.io/bootstrapped/debug/jqWXmM/

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the last character is a "/" and remove it:

Something like this:

```
jQuery(
var pathName = window.location.pathname;
//check if last character is /
if (pathName[pathName.length - 1] == "/")
{
   pathName = pathName.substring(0, pathName.length - 1);
}
'.list-group-item a[href$="' + pathName  +'"]').addClass("active")
 .parents('.panel .panel-heading a').collapse('show');
```